# PDF error while loading pdf in Vue js using vue-pdf

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf

I try to use vue-pdf to preview online pdf file on my production server. But I got blank page and there is no error only somecode like this on console:
Warning: getHexString - ignoring invalid character: 116

```
pdf.worker.js?069e:1869 Warning: getHexString - ignoring invalid character: 109
2pdf.worker.js?069e:1869 Warning: getHexString - ignoring invalid character: 108
pdf.worker.js?069e:1869 Warning: getHexString - ignoring additional invalid characters.
pdf.worker.js?069e:1869 Warning: getHexString - ignoring invalid character: 104
pdf.worker.js?069e:1869 Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
```

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <pdf src="./assets/Manual.pdf"></pdf>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

export default {
    components: {
        pdf,
    },
    data() {
        return {}
    },
}
</script>
```

i follow the step on npm install vue-pdf but it seems no error on this only blank page
[image]

Comment: the word `react` in the title is concerning ... you have loaded `vue` and *compiled* that `.vue` file?

Comment: @JaromandaX just fix my question